# Modifying a CSS style

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling creating a CSS style.

This is what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/WhNRK/26/

It was designed for a label, but now I'm trying to modifying for something like this:

```
<input type='radio' name='mcq' id='radio-choice-1' value='1' /> 
<div class='container'>
<label for="radio-choice-1" onclick="">Choice 1</label>
</div>
```

So if I did this, I broke up the design. Someone can help a little bit? This is a radiobutton style for an iPad.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: What style are you trying to apply to which element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the CSS selector to match your new markup:

```css
#question input:checked + div > label {
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WhNRK/39/)

Answer (score 1):

You just remove `#question input` from your css and make the name of `#question label` as `#question label`.

Change the code as follows:

```
<div id='question'><form name='mcForm'>
  <div class='container'>
    <input type='radio' name='mcq' id='radio-choice-1' value='1' /> 
    <label for="radio-choice-1" onclick="">Choice 1</label>
  </div>
</div>
```